# Socket.io conditional filter per client on serverside

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I read a lot about Socket.io and experimenting right now with it.
What I get that you've `rooms` and `namespaces` on server-side and that you can have endless topics which will always being sent to the client and are discarded at the client side if there is no listener for.

I want to filter messages on the server which are not relevant for the client to limit the amount of traffic. I want to filter based on a condition (if `latitude` and `longitude` is in the specific bounding box of map on the client).

I was thinking to store the bounding box (x1,x2,y1,y2) of each client on the server and filter the events based on the stored bounding box.

Is it possible to store a property on the client object?

Original code:

```js
// Initiate Socket.io logic.
io.on('connection', client => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    client.on('message', (msg) => {
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
        io.emit('message', msg);
    });
    client.on('event', data => { 
        console.log("event: " + data)
     });
    client.on('disconnect', () => { 
        console.log('a user disconnected'); 
    });
});
```

Is it possible to store a property on the client object?

```js
    client.on('setBoundingBox', (msg) => {
        this.boundingBox = msg // <------- IS IT POSSIBLE TO STORE A PROPERTY ON THE CLIENT OBJECT?
    });
```

And filter on that property on each broadcast message?

**Alternative ideas**
The alternative ideas that I had is:

1. To use 'rooms' to subscribe on.
2. Just filter on client-side and don't concern about the amount of traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do it. You'll have to manage the `client` object. Something like this in your case,

```
client.on('setBoundingBox', (msg) => {
    client.boundingBox = msg 
});
```

Now you'll have the `boundingBox` as long as you have the connection(`client`) object.

Comment: Great. I tried it with this. But client is indeed the good scope. I tried it with this peace of code and seems that it's indeed stick to that specific client.

Comment: Do you also know if there is a function which is called on client object on each emit? Then I can just do io.emit(message, 'message') and each client object (on serverside) will check if it's relevant for him.

Comment: you'll have to establish a proper protocol for instance have an unique identifier for each `client` object, have that identifier in `to` and `from` field, then filter all the connections with `to` field and send to that particular client. I'll suggest open a new question for this in case you face an issue

Answer (score 0):

**Final solution**

```js
// Initiate Socket.io logic.
io.on('connection', client => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    client.emit("getBoundingBox", "1"); // In case server restarts we need to fetch it from the client.
    client.on('setBoundingBox', (msg) => {
        client.boundingBox = msg.split(',')
        console.log('message: ' + msg + ' | ' + client.boundingBox);
    });
    client.on('disconnect', () => { 
        console.log('a user disconnected'); 
    });
});

// Events is an array of messages to process. 
// Each message have a property .location.coordinates which is an array [4, 50] (x,y)
for (const event of events) {
    const msg = event.body
    if (msg.location === undefined) {
        continue;
    }
    io.sockets.sockets.forEach(async (o) => {
        const box = o.boundingBox;
        if (box === undefined) {
            return;
        }
        const x = msg.location.coordinates[0];
        const y = msg.location.coordinates[1];
        if (x > box[0] && x < box[1] && y > box[2] && y < box[3]) {
            o.emit("message", msg.location.coordinates);
        } else {
            console.log(`Not in bounding box '${msg.location.coordinates}'`);
        }
    });
}
```